How do i install an app from the web?
I installed linux about 10 minutes ago, and i downloaded a .deb file and it opens the archive, and also i downloaded a .rpm file, does it work just like windows or not?

Which distro and version of Linux did you install?

No, it does not work like Windows. You must learn new habits. Open your Ubuntu Software application and install from there. Installing random deb files from the internet may break your system.

copy the *.deb file to your /home directory and use this command: sudo dpkg -i *.deb

RPM files are for Red Hat, SusE and other systems; as Ubuntu uses deb packages like Debian does. You can convert one package type to another; or use tools that will install foreign packages like RPM, but they require more maintenance/homework, such that if you're asking about them; I'd advice not.  Starting point is what you're actually running though; which you've not stated. What Ubuntu product & release are you using?
